# When let realm = Realm() -> Call can throw, but is not marked with try and the error is not handled

Tags: xcode, swift, realm

I just migrated my project from Swift 1.2 to Swift 2 with Xcode 7 (App store version).  I'm using Realm for local storage and updated the library accordingly.

But whenever in my code I did this:

```
let realm = Realm()
```

I get an Xcode error of:

```
Call can throw, but is not marked with try and the error is not handled
```

Any ideas what I should do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32232649/1135737) will help you.
Use the code below:

```
 let realm = try! Realm()
```